# Icon at end of progressbar indicator

Tags: html, css, frontend

I need to be able to add an icon/image at the right corner of the HTML5 progress bar value indicator (the sub-bar inside the progressbar that represents the value) without switching to slider using JQuery UI or any other alternative solutions.

The challenge is to make it work using that element and no rewritings or external libraries if possible.

[An example to illustrate could be this image](https://www.alamy.com/progress-bar-set-loading-status-bar-web-indicator-process-download-image155380367.html)

If you look at the third one from the bottom with the circle with two grey colours inside at the "tip" of the value progress indicator.

Any tips or thoughts?

Comment: Hmmm, an example to illustrate could be this image: https://www.alamy.com/progress-bar-set-loading-status-bar-web-indicator-process-download-image155380367.html if you look at the third one from the bottom with the circle with two grey colours inside at the "tip" of the value progress indicator

Comment: You sure are new to Stack Overflow, welcome here !

Please provide example of what you tried, and if possible a https://jsfiddle.net/ or any other javascript interpreter online so we can iterate on your code more easily. 

Plus, one should not add any 'not question related' message in your post, so you can delete "Kind Regards" and "Peter".

Comment: Thank you Alburkerk. I have used Stack Overflow quite a lot. In this particular case I am not able to provide an example, given special circumstances *Heavy NDA etc). However, I believe my description together with the link perhaps should be enough. If not, I will of course attempt to add more information

Comment: check this: https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/ogoXwG

Comment: The example provided is of a range element, which is very nice and looks like what I am looking for, however, if possible, I need for this to be as part of a progress element as there is so much connected to the progress element already, that changing it to a "range" element will be detriemental to the overall solution.